# Sets of vectors with a particular property

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

Suppose I have two sets, $A$ and $B$, each of which contains a number of $n$-dimensional vectors. Each of the elements of these vectors are real and non-negative. I want these sets to have the property that $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b} = 1$ whenever $\mathbf{a}\in A$ and $\mathbf{b}\in B$. Here, $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}$ is the usual dot product, i.e. $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_i a_i b_i$.

There are a few easy ways to construct examples of this, but my question is about how to properly characterise the set of all possible solutions.

One example is where $A=\{(1/2,1/2)\}$ and $B = \{(1,1),(1/2,3/2)\}$, but this isn't a very interesting example because $A$ only has one element. A slightly more interesting example is $A=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0)\}$, $B=\{(1,0,0),(1,0,1)\}$, but that relies on elements of the vectors being zero.

My first question is, is there an example where both $A$ and $B$ have more than one element, and all of the elements of each vector are positive?

My second question is, is there a straightforward way to construct the set of all possible sets $A$ and $B$, given $n$ (the dimensionality of the vector space) and the number of elements in $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Suggestions for tags and a better title are very welcome. I used [tag:probability-theory] because the vectors of non-negative reals are somewhat like probability distributions. (In fact, the context of this is a probability theory problem, though I didn't express it that way.)

Comment: For your first question: In the 3D-case, have you tried to rotate the vectors in $A$ and $B$ by an arbitrarily small angle in the $y$ and $z$ planes in such a way that the zero elements become positive? The dot product would be preserved under such rotations.

Comment: @ekkilop it's not clear to me that such a rotation is possible. I'm not sure I understand your intention correctly, but it seems equivalent to rotating $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ by the same angle, such that the elements of both vectors become positive. This is certainly impossible.

Comment: You are right, that won't work...

Comment: In two dimensions it is not possible to construct non-empty $A$ and $B$ with only positive coordinates. In three or more dimensions it is not difficult; I give a three-dimensional example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

What follows is in $\mathbb{R^3}$ (with a 2D interpretation).

Let us begin by a solution :

$A=\{(0.5,2,1),(0.5,1,2)\}$ with for example $B=\{(0.8,0.2,0.2),(1.4,0.1,0.1)\}, $

and *more generally*, keeping the same set $A$,  $B$ is the (infinite) set of all vectors of the form $(2-6t,t,t)$ for $0 < t < 1/3$.

Here is a general method that explains the crucial aspect of the choice of $A$ (that I have used to find the particular case presented upwards).

> Being given the set $A=\{(a,b,c),(a'b'c')\}$ in the positive orthant $\Omega:=\mathbb{R_+^3}$, find under which conditions on $a,b,c,a',b',c'$ does the following system
>
> $$\tag{1}\begin{cases}ax+by+cz&=&1\\a'x+b'y+c'z&=&1\\\end{cases}$$
>
> possess solutions $(x,y,z) \in \Omega$.

(1) can be written under the following equivalent form:

$$\tag{2} \text{Find} \ \ x,y,z >0 \ \ \text{such that} \ \ x\binom{a}{a'}+y\binom{b}{b'}+z\binom{c}{c'}=\binom{1}{1}.$$

A **necessary and sufficient** condition for (2) to hold is as follows:

> Let $P\binom{a}{a'}, Q\binom{b}{b'}, R\binom{c}{c'}$. Let $\Delta$ be the bissector line of the positive quadrant in $\mathbb{R^2}$, and $\Delta_-$, resp. $\Delta_+$ the open regions delimited by $\Delta$ (polar angles $<\pi/4$, resp. $>\pi/4$ ; see figure).
>
> There is a solution to (1) iff triangle $PQR$ is a non-flat triangle crossed by $\Delta$.

(i.e., not all $P,Q,R$ in $\Delta_+$ and not all in $\Delta_-).$

[image]
Proof:

If $P\binom{a}{a'},Q\binom{b}{b'},R\binom{c}{c'}$ are all in $\Delta_+$ or all in $\Delta_-$,  any linear combination of them with positive coefficients will still be in the same region, leading to an impossibility to have the RHS of (2) as their sum.

In a reverse manner (see figure), let us assume that e.g., $P \in \Delta_-$ and $Q, R \in \Delta_+$, line $\Delta$ crosses triangle $PQR$ in two points $S$ and $T$. Let $I$ be the midpoint of $[ST]$, with coordinates $(\alpha,\alpha)$ for a certain $\alpha$. $I$ has what is called **barycentrical coordinates** $(x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ with $x_0,y_0,z_0>0$ and $x_0+y_0+z_0=1$ such that:

$$x_0\binom{a}{a'}+y_0\binom{b}{b'}+z_0\binom{c}{c'}=\binom{\alpha}{\alpha}.$$

It suffices then to take $x=x_0/\alpha, \ y=y_0/\alpha, z=z_0/\alpha $ in order that (2) is fullfilled.

Now, why are there an *infinite* number of solutions for (2) ? Two different reasons can be given

- (i) Any point $I$ between $S$ and $T$ (not necessarily their midpoint) could have been taken, and thus could have generate a solution.
- (ii) Because (1) (unless $(a,b,c)$ and $(a',b',c')$ are proportional) is the intersection of 2 planes, i.e., represents a straight line passing by $(x_0/\alpha,y_0/\alpha,z_0/\alpha)$, i.e, of the form $(x,y,z)=(x_0/\alpha+pt,y_0/\alpha+qt,z_0/\alpha+rt), \ t \in \mathbb{R}$. Simple continuity arguments show that such a line has an infinite number of points in $\Omega$.

Remark : $(p,q,r)$ introduced above can clearly be taken as the cross product of $(a,b,c)$ and $(a',b',c')$.

**Appendix:** If $A$ has three elements, one can evidently extend this reasoning. But the  additional constraint $a''x+b''y+c''z=1$ in relationship (1) gives (if the equivalent condition of being in a certain triangle is fulfilled) a *unique* solution $(x,y,z) \in \Omega$ in the general case. Thus $A$ has three elements but $B$ has only one. For $n>3$, there are no solutions in the general case ((1) turns into an overdetermined system).

**In conclusion** : one can say in a certain sense that $A$ is represented by triangle $PQR$ and $B$ is represented by line segment $[ST]$.

Comment: I am going to give an Edit to my answer of how I have found such solutions.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I look forward to the edit.

Comment: It's interesting that this relies on the elements of $B$ having duplicated elements, and this leads me to wonder whether it's possible to come up with examples that don't rely on this. (I will be quite happy if it isn't!)

Comment: You can be happy :) it will be the case (as in my example) if and only if the triangle $(a,a'), (b,b'), (c,c')$ is symmetrical with respect to straight line $x=y$

Comment: (ctd) Instead of speaking of straight line $(y=x)$ which can be ambiguous (risk of confusion with the $(x,y,z)$ space which is something else) I should say that we have such a large degree of freedom for the choice of (a,a'), (b,b'), (c,c'), that it is a pity (as I have done) to take such a particular case : $a=a'$, $b=c'$, $c=b'$ ... :)

Comment: I have changed the necessary and sufficient condition into a different and more general one : in fact I have realized that the previous one was only a sufficient condition.

Comment: A figure has been added.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of linear algebra, and without looking at the signs of the coordinates of the involved vectors, you can say the following: Each $B$-vector defines a hyperplane $H_i\!:\ {\bf b}_i\cdot{\bf x}=1$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$. The intersection $S:=\bigcap_{i=1}^r H_i$ of these hyperplanes is an affine subspace of ${\mathbb R}^n$ of dimension $n-r$ or greater. The configuration $(A,B)$ is admissible if all vectors ${\bf a}_k\in A$ are lying in $S$.

The constraint which is difficult to handle is that all involved coordinates should be $\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

To get towards a classification, let us first make some simplifying observations.  Suppose you have a good set $(A,B)$.  Given any vector $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in A$ whose coordinates are all positive, define $A'$ by rescaling $A$ by a factor $a_i^{-1}$ in the $i$th direction.  To preserve inner products, let $B'$ be obatined by scaling $B$ by a factor $a_i$ in the $i$th direction.  These scaling operations preserve positivity and inner products between vectors in $A$ and $B$, so the scaled pair $(A', B')$ is still good, and now we have $(1, 1, ..., 1) \in A'$.

In particular, this means that every vector in $B'$ must satisfy $\sum_i b_i = 1$ as well as $b_i > 0$ for all $i$.  This means $B'$ lies in the interior of the convex of the set of basis vectors, $\{ e_i : 1 \le i \le n \}$ (where $e_i$ is $1$ in the $i$th coordinate and $0$ everywhere else).  Let us denote this interior by $F^0$.

Now to generate a good pair, fix any subset $B' \subseteq F^0$.  As has been mentioned in the previous answers, every point $\vec{b} \in B'$ defines a hyperplane $H_{\vec{b}} = \{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \vec{x} \cdot \vec{b} = 1 \}$.  Note that, since $\sum_i b_i = 1$, we must have $\vec{1} = (1, 1, ..., 1) \in H_{\vec{b}}$.  Hence, setting $\vec{y} = \vec{x} - \vec{1}$, we can translate by $\vec{1}$ and work with the subspace $V_{\vec{b}} = \{ \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \vec{y} \cdot \vec{b} = 0 \} = \{ \vec{b} \}^{\perp}$.

We want this condition to hold for *every* vector in $B'$, so we consider the intersection of all of these subspaces, $V = \cap_{\vec{b} \in B'} V_{\vec{b}} = (B')^{\perp}$, the orthogonal space to $B'$.  Note that since $V$ is a subspace, it is always non-empty (since $\vec{0} \in V$).  Moreover, its dimension is equal to $n - \dim \operatorname{span}(B')$.  Hence if $B'$ is full-dimensional, then $V$ will only consist of $\vec{0}$; otherwise $V$ will have infinitely many points.

Finally, we must take care of the positivity requirement.  We want all vectors $\vec{x} \in A'$ to have positive coordinates.  However, recall that $V$ was obtained by translating by $\vec{1}$.  Thus we are interested in the set $S = \{ \vec{y} \in V : \forall i, y_i > -1 \}$.  Note that this contains an open ball around the origin, and so is non-empty (and in fact has the same dimension as $V$).  Now we can get the set $A'$ by taking any subset of $S$ and translating back by $\vec{1}$; that is, any subset $A' \subseteq S'$ will do, where $S' = \{ \vec{y} + \vec{1} : \vec{y} \in S \}$.

This gives us a good pair $(A', B')$ with $\vec{1} \in A'$.  For full generality, we can rescale the coordinates; given any positive reals $\lambda_i$, $1 \le i \le n$, define the set $A$ by rescaling $A'$ by a factor of $\lambda_i$ in the $i$th direction, and the set $B$ by rescaling $B'$ by a factor $\lambda_i^{-1}$ in the $i$th direction.  This gives a fully general pair $(A,B)$ satisfying the requirements.

TLDR: Let $B'$ be a set of vectors with positive coordinates that sum up to $1$; let $S$ be the vectors in the orthogonal complement of the span of $B'$ whose coordinates are all bigger than $1$, and get $A'$ by adding $\vec{1}$ to every vector in some subset of $S$.  Now, for some positive $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$, get the pair $(A,B)$ by scaling $A'$ by $\lambda_i$ and $B'$ by $\lambda_i^{-1}$ in the $i$th direction for each $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Working in $n$ dimensions, let's suppose $A$ contains some positive number of vectors. Choose a vector in $A$ and call this vector $a_1$. The set of all vectors $b$ such that $a_1 \cdot b = 1$ is the hyperplane of $n - 1$ dimensions perpendicular to $a_1$ passing through the point at displacement $\frac{a_1}{\|a_1\|^2}$ from the origin on the same side of the origin as $a_1$. So $B$ must be a subset of that hyperplane.

If we suppose there is another element of $A$, call it $a_2$, where $a_2\neq a_1$, it follows that $B$ must be a subset of the hyperplane of $n - 1$ dimensions perpendicular to $a_2$ passing through the point at displacement $\frac{a_2}{\|a_2\|^2}$ from the origin on the same side of the origin as $a_2$. In fact, $B$ must be a subset of the intersection of the two hyperplanes already described. If $a_2$ is a scalar multiple of $a_1$, the intersection is empty; otherwise it is a hyperplane of dimension $n-2$.

If there is a third vector in $A$, it could be linearly independent of $a_1$ and $a_2$, in which case $B$ is a subset of a hyperplane of dimension $n-3$ that is the intersection of the three hyperplanes determined by the three vectors; or the third vector could be a linear combination of the form $ra_1 + (1-r)a_2$ where $r$ is any real number, in which case it does not make any new restriction on $B$. That is, once we have two vectors in $A$ an entire one-dimensional line within the vector space (or any subset of that line) can be included in $A$ "free of charge."

Continuing in this fashion, if we identify $k$ linearly independent vectors in $A$ then these vectors determine an $(n-k)$-dimensional hyperplane of which $B$ must be a subset, as well as a $(k-1)$-dimensional hyperplane of which $A$ must be a subset.

In three dimensions, if we want $A$ and $B$ each to contain more than one vector, each of the sets $A$ and $B$ must be a subset of a line in the vector space. Setting aside (until later) the requirement that coordinates be positive, an example is when $A=\{(x,0,1) \mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ and 
$B=\{(0,y,1) \mid y\in\mathbb R\}$. We can also have $A=\{(x,0,a) \mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ and $B=\{(0,y,\frac1a) \mid y\in\mathbb R\}$ where $a$ is a non-zero real constant, and we can apply a rotation about the origin simultaneously to these two lines and get two new lines that are suitable to contain $A$ and $B$. Note that any rotation that takes $(0,0,1)$ to a point with only positive coordinates will cause the two lines also to contain segments with only positive coordinates.

For example, let $A$ be any subset of the line through $(\frac23,\frac53,2)$ and $(\frac32,\frac54,\frac34)$ and let $B$ be any subset of the line through $(\frac38,\frac14,\frac16)$ and $(\frac3{10},\frac25,\frac1{15})$.
In case you're wondering how I found those particular points, I guessed the line $(2,1,0)+t(-2,1,3)$ (in parametric form) would contain some points that avoided zeros and duplicated coordinates, let that be the line containing $A$, solved for the line containing $B$, which is $(0,1,-\frac13)+u(1,-2,\frac43)$, and picked two suitable points on each line.

Comment: "we can apply any rotation about the origin simultaneously" : no, this operation will drive almost surely one at least among the points of $A$ or $B$ outside the positive orthant as underlined by @Nathaniel in an answer is a similar proposition.

Comment: @JeanMarie I did not account for positive coordinates when first writing the answer. But it is easy to satisfy that requirement by rotation; even if we move $(0,0,1)$ with uniform distribution over the unit sphere, we have $1/8$ probability to find parts of the two lines in the desired octant. I have added the condition to that part of the answer.